# tinyxml2 - indent with tab instead of spaces

Tags: tinyxml2

I am using tinyxml2 and the system saves my xmls with 4 spaces for indents instead of a tab. The program that reads this only reads in tabs and is giving me errors. Is there anyway I can change tinyxml2 to use tab instead of 4 spaces ? I have tried

```
    XMLDocument xmlDoc(true, PRESERVE_WHITESPACE);
```

but it is not changing anything

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're saving the xml document by calling
    `XMLDocument::SaveFile(const char* filename, bool compact=false)`
    (or `XMLDocument::SaveFile(FILE* fp, bool compact=false)` ).

These methods use the `XMLPrinter` class which writes 4 spaces for the indentation of elements (method `XMLPrinter::PrintSpace`). You can suppress writing of indentation and newlines by passing `true` for the `compact` parameter to `SaveFile`. Compact is preferred when passing xml directly from one application to another. And maybe your program will accept xml in this form.

Changing the indentation character(s) will require that you overload `XMLPrinter` to provide your own implementation of `PrintSpace` and overload `XMLDocument` to use your XMLPrinter.

Note that whitespace (newlines and indentation) between elements in a XML document has no significance and will be (must be) ignored by conforming parsers. It is for human readability only.

`PRESERVE_WHITESPACE` / `COLLAPSE_WHITESPACE` only affects how whitespace characters are handled in within the text node of an element.